# Get Ethernet connection ID from nmcli output

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am trying to get the Ethernet connection IDs from nmcli's output as below:

```
user@user-desktop:~/$ nmcli c
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE 
Wi-Fi connection 1  fb03ea1d-7aa5-48f2-b94d-c7f0f8249a7e  802-11-wireless  wlp2s0 
Wired connection 1  4091d179-ccde-34be-938e-5bc792fd1e1b  802-3-ethernet   eno1
```

I would like to get **fb03ea1d-7aa5-48f2-b94d-c7f0f8249a7e** and **4091d179-ccde-34be-938e-5bc792fd1e1b**.

For that, I used the command below:

```
user@user-desktop:~/$nmcli connection | awk '{print $4}' | sed 1,1d
fb03ea1d-7aa5-48f2-b94d-c7f0f8249a7e
4091d179-ccde-34be-938e-5bc792fd1e1b
```

The command is working fine. But when the connection name is "Wi-Fi_connection_1" for instance, the command will not give the expected values.

Is there any generic way to do this properly?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `awk`, as `nmcli` already provides methods to present the desired output to your scripts. For some reason, the answer that @mdepot gave is not working for me (although indeed the `-g` or `--get-values` option is mentioned in the man pages, it's not recognized by my version of `nmcli`).

```
nmcli -t -f UUID con
```

will provide the output you are expecting. The `-t` option (--terse) makes the output easily readable by scripts, while the `-f` option (--fields) expects a list of fields you are interested in as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your command is that awk is using the space character as a field separator, but there may or may not be spaces in the name of the connection.

The nmcli command has a --get-values (-g) option that you can use to get just the fields you are interested in.

To get connection names only:

```
nmcli -g name con
```

To get connection uuids only:

```
nmcli -g uuid con
```

Comment: If you need to get multiple values, like the connection type and the name, just stick it next to `name` or `uuid` it with a comma, such as: `nmcli -g name,type con`. They'll be separated with `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, (now included here):

Run your command as

```
nmcli c | cat -vet
```

If you see `^I` chars surrounding the UUID then

```
nmcli c | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'
```

should work.

Else, probably not the one-liner you were hoping for, but this will deal with any resizing of output that `nmcli` is likely to throw at you.

```
cat getUUID.awk

# given  as intput
# NAME                UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE
# Wi-Fi connection 1  fb03ea1d-7aa5-48f2-b94d-c7f0f8249a7e  802-11-wireless  wlp2s0
# Wired connection 1  4091d179-ccde-34be-938e-5bc792fd1e1b  802-3-ethernet   eno1
#

NR==1{
  start=end=$0
  sub(/UUID.*$/,"",start)
  startL=length(start)+1
  sub(/TYPE.*$/,"",end)
  endL=length(end)-startL
  #dbg print "#dbg:startL=" startL "\tendL="endL
}
NR!=1{
  print substr($0,startL,endL)
}

# for output
# fb03ea1d-7aa5-48f2-b94d-c7f0f8249a7e
# 4091d179-ccde-34be-938e-5bc792fd1e1b
```

Run it as

```
nmcli c | awk -f getUUID.awk
```

Oh, and here it is as a one-liner (without comments):

```
nmcli c | awk -f 'NR==1{ st=end=$0; sub(/UUID.*$/,"",st);stL=length(st)+1;sub(/TYPE.*$/,"",end); endL=length(end)-stL} NR!=1{print substr($0,stL,endL)}'
```

*I don't have access to a system with `nmcli` right now, so I can't do a complete test of this.*

IHTH